# Daemon sync never starting - can't receive my funds

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon, synchronization

I'm pretty new to Monero and I've checked many FAQ's or forums to solve this issue, but I can't find a good answer. I've recently bought some Monero coins on Agoradesk. Sent it to my Monero GUI wallet, but it keeps saying : "Waiting for Daemon to sync". I have already disabled my firewall settings, VPN out...etc

I also find this message in the log :

[6/04/21 14:03] 2021-04-06 12:03:03.403 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.1.9-release)
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

How can I solve the issue and get my funds?

Answer (score 1):

Your wallet version is up to date. Your wallet is telling you it can't reach the daemon.
To see why the demon fails to start, check the $HOME/.bitmonero/bitmonero.log, you should have information about any error at the end of it. You might have to add "--log-level 1" in the wallet settings page as daemon parameters to get more verbosity in the daemon logs.